# Oracle SQL generate random output with listaggs

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the values 30, 31, 32 and 33

How could I generate a output (random) which may contain single values of that list, listaggs of them or nulls?

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30, 31 |
| 2 | null |
| 3 | 32 |
| 4 | 33 |
| 5 | null |
| 6 | 31, 33 |
| 7 | null |
| 8 | 30 |

Comment: Fix your data model, so you are not storing numbers in strings, nor multiple values in a single column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way - generating the strings quasi-randomly (using `ora_hash` to do the trick), while in a perfectly deterministic, reproducible way. If you want to get different (but similar) results, use the third argument to `ora_hash` to provide a seed different from the default (which is 0). If you want different results every time, provide a `dbms_random.value()` value as the seed; this will still require just one "random" value to be generated for the entire query. You can also play with the upper bound (in my example, 280) to get more or fewer `null` (and shorter vs. longer comma-separated strings, more generally).

```
WITH data ( value ) AS (
  SELECT 30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 31 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 32 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 33 FROM DUAL
),
ids ( id ) AS (
  SELECT LEVEL
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 8
)
select id, 
       ( select listagg(case when ora_hash(id * value, 1000) < 280 
                             then value end, ',')
                        within group(order by value)
         from   data
       ) as vals
from   ids
;

ID VALS           
-- ---------------
 1 33             
 2 32             
 3                
 4 30,32          
 5 30,31          
 6 32             
 7                
 8
```

Comment: Hats off to this answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it but you need to add some seemingly irrelevant filters to force the SQL optimiser to not materialize the sub-query and to ensure the values are randomly generated for each row:

```sql
WITH data ( value ) AS (
  SELECT 30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 31 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 32 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 33 FROM DUAL
),
ids ( id ) AS (
  SELECT LEVEL
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 8
)
SELECT id,
       ( 
         SELECT LISTAGG( value, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY value )
         FROM   (
           SELECT value,
                  DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() AS rnd
           FROM   data
           WHERE  ROWNUM > 0          -- force a new random on each row.
         )
         WHERE rnd < 0.5
         AND id > 0                   -- force the query to correlate with the outer query.
       ) AS vals
FROM   ids;
```

Which may output:

> | ID | VALS |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 33 |
> | 2 | 30,31,32 |
> | 3 | 31,32 |
> | 4 | *<null>* |
> | 5 | 30,32 |
> | 6 | 31,33 |
> | 7 | 30,31,32,33 |
> | 8 | 30,31,32,33 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1ea3b0b5012dd3ec4457e41f3ac288f6)*

Comment: Thanks! I assume that, if I tweak WHERE rnd < 0.5 to, let's say, 0.2, more null values will appear?