# I want to take thus code for stratified sampling in SQL server and convert it to Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, sampling

```
WITH row_count AS (
    select s1.rec_count, (0.313733*s1.rec_count)/(0.0001*(s1.rec_count-1)+0.313733) as calc_count from ( 
        SELECT count(*) AS rec_count
        FROM staging.denodo_sample_clinical_event_s1 a
        INNER JOIN DENODO.DIM_CLINICAL_EVENT_CLASS b ON a.CLINICAL_EVENT_CLASS_ID = b.CLINICAL_EVENT_CLASS_ID
        WHERE b.CLINICAL_EVENT_SAMPLE_GROUP = 's7_Radiology'
        )s1
)
SELECT s.clinical_event_id,s.clinical_event_class_id,s.clinical_event_code_id
    FROM staging.denodo_sample_clinical_event_s1 s
    INNER JOIN denodo.dim_clinical_event_class d ON d.clinical_event_class_id = s.clinical_event_class_id
    cross join row_count c
    WHERE d.clinical_event_sample_group = 's7_Radiology'
      AND c.calc_count/c.rec_count >= CAST(CHECKSUM(NEWID(), s.clinical_event_id) & 0x7fffffff AS float) 
    / CAST (0x7fffffff AS int);
```

Comment: Okay, good luck. Or do you have a question?

Comment: Any particular part of this code porting you are stuck on? The syntax here is pretty simple. Besides the CASTs at the end (maybe) it should be 1:1

Comment: sorry, my question is .... I don't know how to do it. Can you help?

Comment: I'm stuck on the "CAST(CHECKSUM(NEWID(), s.clinical_event_id) & 0x7fffffff AS float) 
    / CAST (0x7fffffff AS int);" part

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain (in words) what your code is trying to achieve (particularly the `c.calc_count/c.rec_count >= CAST(CHECKSUM(NEWID(), s.clinical_event_id) & 0x7fffffff AS float) / CAST (0x7fffffff AS int);` part).

Answer (score 2):

[`CHECKSUM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/checksum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) returns as integer that is a hash of the argument values.

[`NEWID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) generates a random GUID.

So, you appear to be hashing a random GUID and an event id which will give you a (semi?) random number and then performing a binary `AND` to restrict it to an upper-bound and then dividing by that upper-bound to get a decimal value in the range from `0` to `1`.

If you just want a random value in the range from `0` to less than `1` then use [`DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/arpls/DBMS_RANDOM.html#GUID-AAD9E936-D74F-440D-9E16-24F3F0DE8D31).

Which would make your query:

```sql
WITH row_count AS (
  select rec_count,
         (0.313733*rec_count)/(0.0001*(rec_count-1)+0.313733) as calc_count
  from   ( 
    SELECT count(*) AS rec_count
    FROM   staging.denodo_sample_clinical_event_s1 a
           INNER JOIN DENODO.DIM_CLINICAL_EVENT_CLASS b
           ON a.CLINICAL_EVENT_CLASS_ID = b.CLINICAL_EVENT_CLASS_ID
    WHERE b.CLINICAL_EVENT_SAMPLE_GROUP = 's7_Radiology'
  )
)
SELECT s.clinical_event_id,
       s.clinical_event_class_id,
       s.clinical_event_code_id
FROM   staging.denodo_sample_clinical_event_s1 s
       INNER JOIN denodo.dim_clinical_event_class d
       ON d.clinical_event_class_id = s.clinical_event_class_id
       cross join row_count c
WHERE  d.clinical_event_sample_group = 's7_Radiology'
AND    c.calc_count/c.rec_count >= DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE();
```

If you find that the random values are not being randomly generated for each cross join then you may need to use a technique [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67423996/oracle-sql-generate-random-output-with-listaggs/67425134#67425134) and include some seemingly irrelevant filters. (However, we don't have your tables or data so I am unsure if it would be necessary).

Or, if you want to use [`ORA_HASH`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions136.htm#SQLRF06313):

```sql
WITH row_count AS (
  select rec_count,
         (0.313733*rec_count)/(0.0001*(rec_count-1)+0.313733) as calc_count
  from   ( 
    SELECT count(*) AS rec_count
    FROM   staging.denodo_sample_clinical_event_s1 a
           INNER JOIN DENODO.DIM_CLINICAL_EVENT_CLASS b
           ON a.CLINICAL_EVENT_CLASS_ID = b.CLINICAL_EVENT_CLASS_ID
    WHERE b.CLINICAL_EVENT_SAMPLE_GROUP = 's7_Radiology'
  )
)
SELECT s.clinical_event_id,
       s.clinical_event_class_id,
       s.clinical_event_code_id
FROM   staging.denodo_sample_clinical_event_s1 s
       INNER JOIN denodo.dim_clinical_event_class d
       ON d.clinical_event_class_id = s.clinical_event_class_id
       cross join row_count c
WHERE  d.clinical_event_sample_group = 's7_Radiology'
AND    c.calc_count/c.rec_count
       >= ORA_HASH(
            SYS_GUID() || s.clinical_event_id,
            134217727,
            FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, 4294967296)) -- random seed
          ) / 134217727;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried your suggestion by got no rows returned. I guess the dbms_random.value() function didn't return any values between 0 and 1.

Comment: MT0 - I inherited the code so I'm not sure what it's doing.

Comment: @cap Then I suggest you talk to someone who does understand it because modifying code that you do not understand is a recipe for generating code that looks as though its the same but actually is not. I've looked at your code for 2 minutes and got to the answers above but I cannot tell you why you would be using that code or if it is correct as that is something I would rely you you, as the subject matter expert, to know; and if you don't know then no-one will.

Comment: I just posted the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO DENODO.SAMPLE_CASE_CLINICAL_EVENT (
CLINICAL_EVENT_ID
,CLINICAL_EVENT_CLASS_ID
,CLINICAL_EVENT_CODE_ID
,EVENT_ID
)
WITH row_count AS (
    SELECT count
        ,(0.313733 * count) / (0.0001 * (count - 1) + 0.313733) AS calc_count
    FROM (
        SELECT count(*) AS count
        FROM DENODO.MT_BASE_CLINICAL_EVENT_98_ETL_SQL a
        INNER JOIN DENODO.DIM_CLINICAL_EVENT_CLASS b ON a.CLINICAL_EVENT_CLASS_ID = b.CLINICAL_EVENT_CLASS_ID
        WHERE b.CLINICAL_EVENT_SAMPLE_GROUP = 's7_Radiology'
        )
    )
SELECT /*+ parallel (5) */ a.CLINICAL_EVENT_ID
,a.CLINICAL_EVENT_CLASS_ID
,a.CLINICAL_EVENT_CODE_ID
,a.EVENT_ID
FROM DENODO.MT_BASE_CLINICAL_EVENT_98_ETL_SQL a
INNER JOIN DENODO.DIM_CLINICAL_EVENT_CLASS b ON 
    a.CLINICAL_EVENT_CLASS_ID = b.CLINICAL_EVENT_CLASS_ID
CROSS JOIN row_count c
WHERE c.calc_count / c.count >= 
    bitand(ORA_HASH(SYS_GUID() || CLINICAL_EVENT_ID), 
    to_number('7fffffff', 'xxxxxxxxx')) / to_number('7fffffff', 'xxxxxxxxx')
  AND CLINICAL_EVENT_SAMPLE_GROUP = 's7_Radiology';
```

Comment: You do not need `BITAND` as `ORAHASH` has a second argument which sets the maximum bucket size (as I use in my answer) and `to_number('7fffffff', 'xxxxxxxxx')` is `134217727` so this just appears to be a slightly different formulation of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help I did use some of your ideas in the final product and it now returns the correct results.