# Oracle database - update table with random value from literal table, but change data per row

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to randomly pick a data tuple from a literal table to fill in another table, and randomize the row to pick each time. With the below query, I fill all rows with the same data, so I think the random row is picked once and used everywhere.

So how can I get a random row for each row to update in the Oracle database?

```sql
update HISTORY h
    set (ORGANIZATION_ID, COMPANY_ID) = (
    select org_id, company_id from (
        select * from (
            select '3.11' as org_id, '11111111' as company_id from dual union
            select '3.22.3' as org_id, '22222222' as company_id from dual union 
            ...
            select '3.44.5' as org_id, '33333333' as company_id from dual
        ) order by DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM
    ) where rownum = 1
) where CODE = '1234567'; -- originally all were 3.88.4 and 88000004. 20707 rows
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [my similar answer to another question on picking random rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67425134/1509264), you can do it but you need to add some seemingly irrelevant filters to force the SQL optimiser to not materialize the sub-query and to ensure the values are randomly generated for each row:

```
MERGE INTO HISTORY h
USING (
  WITH data (org_id, company_id) AS (
    select '3.11',   '11111111' from dual union
    select '3.22.3', '22222222' from dual union 
    select '3.44.5', '33333333' from dual
  )
  SELECT h.ROWID AS rid,
         d.*
  FROM   history h
         CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
           SELECT *
           FROM   data
           WHERE  ROWNUM > 0          -- force a new random on each row
           AND    h.ROWID IS NOT NULL -- force the query to correlate
           ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() DESC
           FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
         ) d
  WHERE  h.code = '1234567'
) d
ON ( h.ROWID = d.RID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET ORGANIZATION_ID = d.org_id,
      COMPANY_ID      = d.company_id;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE history (organization_id, company_id, code) AS
SELECT '123456778', '88888888888', '1234567' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123456778', '88888888888', '1234567' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123456778', '88888888888', '1234567' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123456778', '88888888888', '1234567' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123456778', '88888888888', '1234567' FROM DUAL;
```

Then after the `MERGE`, the table may (randomly) contain:

> | ORGANIZATION_ID | COMPANY_ID | CODE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 3.44.5 | 33333333 | 1234567 |
> | 3.11 | 11111111 | 1234567 |
> | 3.44.5 | 33333333 | 1234567 |
> | 3.22.3 | 22222222 | 1234567 |
> | 3.11 | 11111111 | 1234567 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9933340b718e017d5b33dac6bb3509ff)*

Comment: Thanks! I know it's complicated, but didn't expect this much.

Comment: Hi, one thing I don't understand: where is the constraint of "where CODE = '1234567'"?

Comment: I think it should be added after `h.ROWID = d.RID`, like `(h.ROWID = d.RID and h.CODE = '1234567')`. OK now it works.

Comment: @WesternGun Yes, that would work or you can add a `WHERE` clause to the end of the `SELECT` query in the `USING` clause (which may be slightly more efficient as you then would not need to compare all the rows in the `ON` clause).

Comment: One thing to note is that, in `sqlcl` of Oracle it is fine, but Intellij IDEA plugin Database Navigator is not recognizing the query as legit. Will fire a bug to them.

Comment: @WesternGun There are many issues it could be - either the `MERGE` statement is not recognized or the `LATERAL` join or the `ROWID` pseudo-column or it may not like the sub-query factoring (`WITH`) clause nested inside another statement.

Comment: Anyway I posted a bug report here: https://database-navigator.atlassian.net/browse/DBN-491. But I forgot to link this question in the ticket; but I guess that's irrelevant.